# Microservice resource server how to identify user using oauth2 with spring-security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I'm trying to migrating existing monolithic application to micro-service applications. But get confused of authentication and authorisation strategy with oauth2.0.

Take ordering service as an example, I want to identify the user who is placing order.
1. The user login and get an access token from a separate authentication service.
2. The user (client) submits a place order request with the access token as Authorization header.
3. The ordering service submits a request to the authentication server to verify the access token and then get the user info.

The questions are:
1. each time the ordering service handles a request, it has to interact with the authentication server, does this increase failure risk? e.g. The ordering service fails to accept orders if the authentication server is down.
2. what is the test strategy for integration / functional tests, should I mock the authentication server and if so, how do I do that?
3.Some articles mentioned JWT token to make the authentication server stateless, does this approach alleviate the case and what is the workflow then?

Comment: #1 - You're generally better with using more stateless, e.g. JWT. It holds the user authentication details in it, so you don't need to talk to the authorization server. #2 - You can generate valid tokens in your test that the server will validate, so you can totally ignore the auth server. #3 - Yep, this is what I have been doing for about a year and a half now - it's been pretty simple